# How do I prevent KDE Plasma 6 from blanking the display when I close my laptop's lid?

Tags: arch-linux, kde

I'm running KDE Plasma 6 on Arch Linux with X as the display server.  I'm using NoMachine to remote into my laptop from my desktop.  I like to close the laptop lid while I'm remoted into it through NoMachine.

With later versions of KDE Plasma 5 and KDE Plasma 6, whenever I close the lid of the laptop, the display goes blank even when KDE's power settings are set to ignore the laptop lid being closed.  Since NoMachine just mirrors what's on the physical display, its display goes blank, too.

The laptop isn't going to sleep since I can SSH into the laptop without any issues while the lid is closed and the display goes back to normal when I open the lid without pressing any keys or buttons.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but have you looked at the power settings? I haven't used KDE in years, but on my Cinnamon, the "Power Settings" GUI tool includes options for what to do when the lid is closed, one of which is "nothing". Is there no equivalent in the KDE settings?

Comment: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-change-the-action-when-closing-the-lid/150586/4

Comment: I thought I had stated that in the description, but I updated the description to make it clearer that I had the power settings set to ignore the laptop lid being closed.  It works by not putting the laptop to sleep, but the display still goes blank.

Comment: Huh, that is weird. Do you have another DE installed? If so, can you see if that one behaves correctly? Might be a KDE bug.

Comment: I've had Linux Mint with Cinnamon installed on this laptop and the issue did not occur.  I also just tried KDE Neon 6.0 and the issue also does not occur.  I'll try posting on the Arch Linux forum and see what they have to say.